# Generating columns of variable readings

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I've pulled readings from a database that comes in the format:

```
Host Name | Metric Label | Reading Time | Metric Value
```

I've created a query that pulls all the data and arranges it for each host and metric, ordered as to reading in time.

```
SELECT
    host_name,
    metric_label,
    reading_time,
    metric_value
FROM
    reading_data
GROUP BY
    host_name,
    metric_label
    reading_time
ORDER BY reading_time DESC;
```

However, I'm trying to automatically create columns for each variable at each reading_time, grouped by host names. I'm really not sure how to do this. I'm hoping to get a table in the form:

```
Host Name | Reading Time | Variable 1 | Variable 2 | ... | Variable 107 |
Name 1    | Time 1       | Value 1    | Value 2    | ... | Value 107    |
Name 1    | Time 2       | Value 108  | Value 109  | ... | Value 110    |
```

My database is pretty large and it takes up to 30 mins to run almost any queries. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is probably best handled in the display layer (eg SSRS, Business Objects). If you need to do this int eh DB, look into `PIVOT` for your DBMS of choice

Comment: @JohnHC  `PIVOT` looks promising. Is there any way to loop the generation for each variable, as there are quite a few?

Comment: Yes, but you're getting into the world of dynamic SQL

Comment: Is that a particularly bad thing, as I don't really want to have to write all the variable names out?

Comment: Which database engine are you using? MySQL, SQLServer, Oracle? Not all engines support PIVOT....

Comment: @Neville K I'm using Oracle. I believe that it should work.